# ODBC or ODP.Net for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, odp.net

I've been tasked with writing a few custom C# reporting programs for a client.  These programs will only read the Oracle databases, never update or change the data.

Is there any significant advantage to using ODP.Net over ODBC?  I know several people that advocate using Oracle's Instant Client (I think it includes ODP.Net) because it's easier to deploy (supposedly) than having the client install the ODBC drivers.  Having had no experience with deploying apps that rely on ODBC or ODP.Net, I can't make a good decision.

So, any advice from someone that's been through this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODP.NET! I can vouch for easy deployment with instant client and odp. Definitely the way to go.

Comment: Yes, after doing a little more digging, it appears that ODP is the preferred way to go.  I do appreciate your enthusiastic response!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt use the native ADO.Net Managed Provider for your database in favor of ODBC Drivers.

Comment: Oh no, it's deprecated. Absolutely never use the managed ADO.NET provider.

Comment: no I mean for Microsoft: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx And for anyone using .NET for that matter. By the way it's been pretty long time since they deprecated it. I expect it to completely disappear in future versions of the framework. I hope you are not basing any new development on it and use ODP.NET instead.