# What are the options to connect to an Oracle Database from .NET?

Tags: .net, oracle11g, odbc, odp.net

I am evaluating the best option to connect to an Oracle Database from a .NET application.
I came across ODP.NET, ODBC, DEVART etc. 
Looking for a comparison and what is the best possible solution to connect to an Oracle DB ? Are there any apart from these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODBC is a "lowest common denominator" type interface that does not allow database specific features to be supported.  ODP.NET on the other hand supports both ADO.NET and enhances it with features specific to Oracle (for example RAC, security, datatypes, etc).

Devart's product is not free like ODP.NET is. And some people prefer to get all their software from Oracle when possible for ease and guarantee of support.

Answer (score 0):

I will say ODP.NET compared to ODBC because it is easier to deploy. It makes using Oracle from .NET more flexible, faster, and more stable than ODBC drivers from what i understand.

This thread also discusses something similar [ODBC or ODP.Net for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834084/odbc-or-odp-net-for-c)

All the best